# Truncating text in an ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here's the GridView that displays all columns and records from table in the database:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="5"
        ForeColor="#000066" GridLines="None">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" 
        HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Yellow"
            ControlStyle-ForeColor="Red" SelectText="Select" HeaderText="Select" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
public void ShowBooks()
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Book", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowBooks();
}
```

On this table a column named `Description` have a lot of text. In GridView I want to show only 10 or 20 first characters followed by ... (three dots). When I hover over the text I want the full text to be shown as a tooltip.

Answer (score 5):

There are two solutions to do this. Solutions are in the SQL side and the code side.

**First:**

Truncate Description column value when getting data from database.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Description, 0, 20) FROM Book
```

More information about the `SUBSTRING` function in T-SQL is [here](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-substring.html).

---

**Second:**

You can write a method to crop your string value and to use it in `GridView`. Do not forget; to do this, firstly you should to convert `Description` column field into `TemplateField`.

**Crop method in a helper class:**

```
public static class StringHelper
{
    public static string Crop(this string text, int maxLength)
    {
        if (text == null) return string.Empty;

        if (text.Length < maxLength) return text;

        return text.Substring(0, maxLength);
    }
}
```

**Aspx Side:**

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">               
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# StringHelper.Crop(Eval("Description").ToString(), 20) %>'></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Note that: Do not worry about null values. You will not get `null reference exception` when executed `ToString()` method. I have tested.

---

**Bonus:**

If you do not want to apply `truncate` using with above options, you may using `CSS` `word-wrap` [property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp).

**Your Description column on GridView:**

> <
>   asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"
>   ControlStyle-CssClass="wrappedText" />

**CSS definition:**

```
.wrappedText { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

Notice that CSS class named as **wrappedText**.

Answer (score 3):

Use a TemplateField as shown below:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
    <ItemTemplate>
          <span title='<%#HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Eval("Description").ToString)%>'><%#HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Left(Eval("Description").ToString, 20)) + "..."%></span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

You may want to check and allow for carriage return characters or single quotes in your `Description` field as that may destroy the output.

Comment: Thanks but if I use `TemplateField` to `Bind` the Description field, now on browser the GridView is showing two Description filelds, the one with the truncated text and other with full text.

Comment: One of the description fields is in the title of the span and shouldn't appear. If it is appearing, then you likely have a single quote in the description that is terminating the title attribute. Try adding `.Replace("'","")` and see what happens.

Comment: @user2969489 Are you sure that gridview do not generate auto column? And my answer may be can help you?